# Why is my php script freezing?

Tags: php

What is causing my php code to freeze? I know it's cause of the while loop, but I have $max_threads--; at the end so it shouldn't do that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            $db = mysql_connect("host","name","pass") or die("Can't connect to host");
            mysql_select_db("dbname",$db) or die("Can't connect to DB"); 

            $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(Thread) FROM test_posts", $db);

            $rs = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result);

            $max_threads = $rs[0];

            $board = $_GET['board'];
        ?>



    </head>

    <body>


        <?php


            While($max_threads >= 0)
            {
                $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT MIN(ID) FROM test_posts WHERE Thread=".$max_threads."", $db);
                $rs = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result);

                $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT post FROM test_posts WHERE ID=".$rs[0]."", $db);
                $post = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result);

                $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM test_posts WHERE ID=".$rs[0]."", $db);
                $name = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result);

                $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT trip FROM test_posts WHERE ID=".$rs[0]."", $db);
                $trip = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result);

                if(!empty($post))
                    echo'<div class="postbox"><h4>'.$name[0].'['.$trip[0].']</h4><hr />' . $post[0] . '<br /><hr />[<a href="http://prime.programming-designs.com/test_forum/viewthread.php?thread='.$max_threads.'">Reply</a>]</div>';

                $max_threads--;
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just debug or echo $max_threads before and inside the loop to confirm or rule out it as the cause of the problem.

Comment: Uh, two pieces of advice for you: 1. Use `LIMIT` in your SQL statements and 2. Don't do 4 `SELECT` s when you can do one.

Comment: Can't echo max_threads because it's crashing before the page loads.

Comment: I've never executed php inside the head element. Is that allowed?

Comment: @Catfish: It's perfectly valid. You might want to use it to display the page title, for instance. However, it's completely unnecessary, and kind of silly if you're not outputting any content there.

Comment: Check the error log. Set PHP error reporting as ALL | STRICT as well.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ob_implicit_flush(true);` and you should be able to output `$max_threads`. Be wary that your browser might crash, though, so you might want to use `wget` or something.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd suggest completely getting rid of the extraneous HTML bits. Then, build up your code slowly, line-by-line to see if you can find the offending line. So write a script that just connects to the database and see what happens.

If you find for example that this code...

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect("host","name","pass") or die("Can't connect to host");
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$db) or die("Can't connect to DB"); 
?>
```

...is causing the freeze on its own, then it could easily be a problem with the MySQL server.

However, if the browser itself is crashing, that sounds like an issue with your system rather than something that PHP or MySQL is doing...

Answer (score 2):

Try this 1 SQL query instead of those 1 + (4 * n) queries:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), post, name, trip FROM test_posts GROUP BY Thread
```

Maybe a `LIMIT 50` (or whatever max # of threads to return) at the end as well, that could be a lot of data.

You can just loop over the results of this query instead of `$max_threads` and all the extra db calls, via `while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result)) { /* echo(...); */ }`.

Not sure that's *exactly* the same as what you're trying to fetch without knowing more about the data (getting the root post of each thread in a forum?), but it should be pretty close.

(P.S.: if that's a threaded 2ch-style forum deal, I'm not sure that's an ideal db design.  A parent-child [adjacency list](http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm) might be better than maintaining a number count for each thread.  Just a guess though.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it's because you're hitting the sql database 4 times per loop. Is there any way you can maybe access it all at once, and then parse the incoming data from there?

```
$dbsql = 'SELECT * FROM my_database';
$result = mysql_query($dbsql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     // Parse information here, rather than 
     // accessing the database for individual variables... 
}
```

Something like that.

Update:

Other than what I've already said (and you've dismissed) all I see are some here & there coding quirks:

This part didn't have a space between echo and the string. The 'hr' element didn't have a starting bracket.

```
echo '<div class="postbox"><h4>'.$name[0].'['.$trip[0].']</h4><hr>' . $post[0] . '<br /><hr />[<a href="http://prime.programming-designs.com/test_forum/viewthread.php?thread='.$max_threads.'">Reply</a>]</div>';
```

'while' Shouldn't be capitalized.

```
while($max_threads >= 0)
```

Again, clean code is a good place to start, but that's all I've got, personally. I just recently cleaned up my own site, which was crashing IE (and no other browser), simply because it had too many markup errors. Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe that'll be a problem later, but right now it's a total freeze with only two threads.

Comment: @William: Really, it's a problem now, even if it's not the cause of the freeze. Issuing 4 queries when you only need one is overkill, and  makes the code less readable.

Comment: No, it's not a problem right now because it doesn't matter if the damn thing is freezing and crashing browsers before loading the page, duh.

Comment: @William: When you say "freeze", does it literally crash the browser, or does the PHP just not fully execute?

Comment: It would crash the broswer. x_x

Comment: So what did it turn out being exactly? I'm very curious.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can scatter calls to this simple function in yer code:

```
function of($required)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    var_dump($args);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
of(__LINE__, $max_threads);
```

You can also use something like this for your queries:

```
function mydb_query($query, $db = null)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $result = call_user_func_array('mysql_query', $args);
    if (!$result) {
        of(array(__FUNCTION__), mysql_error(), $sql);
        //return something else?
    }
    return $result;
}
$result = mydb_query("SELECT post, name, trip FROM test_posts WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM test_posts WHERE Thread={$max_threads})", $db);
```

You should use mysqli/PDO/framework with support for prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the script is exceeding the maximum server execution time threshold, try this on the top of your file to confirm this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');
```